# Extract image type from html page using jsoup library in android

Tags: php, android, html, jsoup

```
<div class="_jjzlb" style="padding-bottom: 55.2778%;"><img alt="AT Dam party.. #nashik  #big #dam" class="_icyx7" id="pImage_11" src="https://instagram.fbom1-2.fna.fbcdn.net/t51.2885-15/e35/17438694_254543168340407_6435023364997251072_n.jpg" style=""></div>
```

From above code i have to extract this link- https://instagram.fbom1-2.fna.fbcdn.net/t51.2885-15/e35/17438694_254543168340407_6435023364997251072_n.jpg

*How should i extract the link using jsoup library in android ?*

I have implemented code as follows.

```
class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        Document doc = null;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.instagram.com/p/BR72iDGg8bAcA73KgP0ZqCopjKfvn5wJy1OQE40/").get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Get all elements with img tag ,
        Elements img = doc.getElementsByTag("img");

        String imgSrc = img.attr("src");

        System.out.println("Img source: " + imgSrc);

        return img.toString();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String feed) {

        Log.e("MyTag", "Final links ==" + feed);


    }
}
```

but this code is giving error as--java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.jsoup.select.Elements org.jsoup.nodes.Document.select(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

How to solve this?

Comment: Did you try to access the link `https://www.instagram.com/p/BR72iD...` directly from your browser? You probably have to log to Instagram first in order to access it.

Comment: @TDG yes it is working in browser when i am login. But i have to extract  .jpg  image from this link

Comment: Well, since you're logged in with the browser, you have access to that page. If you try to go to that page without login, you will not success - try to delete the site's cookies from your browser and you'll see what I mean. In your app first you need to login to the site and only then to proceed to the page you want.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to log in .

```
class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        Document doc = null;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.instagram.com/p/BR72iDGg8bAcA73KgP0ZqCopjKfvn5wJy1OQE40/").get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        Elements img = doc.select("img");

        String imgSrc = img.attr("src");

        System.out.println("Img source: " + imgSrc);

        return img.toString();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String feed) {

        Log.e("MyTag", "Final links ==" + feed);


    }
}
```

Comment: View sample application made:
https://myket.ir/app/com.mrandroidi.instadownloader